# MySQL join 3 tables count

Tags: mysql, join

I need help to make a query, hope you can help me. I have these tables:

### Table Offices

`|id |   office   |
|---|------------|
| 1 |   office A |
| 2 |   office B |
| 3 |   office C |`

### Table Animals

`| id  |  animal  |
|-----|----------|
| 1   |   dog    |
| 2   |   cat    |
| 3   |   bird   |
| 4   |   snake  |`

### Table Sales

`| id     |    animal    |    idOffice    |         date         |
|--------|--------------|----------------|----------------------|
| 1      |     dog      |       1        |  2015-06-10 16:57:23 |
| 2      |     cat      |       1        |  2015-06-10 17:47:45 |

| 3      |     dog      |       2        |  2015-06-10 18:20:56 |
| 4      |     snake    |       3        |  2015-06-11 10:33:47 |

| 5      |     bird     |       2        |  2015-06-11 11:41:29 |
| 6      |     snake    |       2        |  2015-06-11 12:59:36 |
| 7      |     cat      |       3        |  2015-06-11 13:01:41 |
| 8      |     dog      |       2        |  2015-06-12 13:56:58 |
| 9      |     cat      |       3        |  2015-06-12 14:17:34 |`

I need this result between date sales(2015-06-10 00:00:00 / 2015-06-12 23:59:59), showing all sales of all animals for each office:

`| Office        |    animal    | num_sales|
|---------------|--------------|----------|
| Office A      |     dog      |     1    |
| Office A      |     cat      |     1    |
| Office A      |     bird     |     0    |
| Office A      |     snake    |     0    |
| Office B      |     dog      |     2    |
| Office B      |     cat      |     0    |
| Office B      |     bird     |     1    |
| Office B      |     snake    |     1    |
| Office C      |     dog      |     0    |
| Office C      |     cat      |     2    |
| Office C      |     bird     |     0    |
| Office C      |     snake    |     1    |`

I try this query but i dont know how to go on:

`SELECT A.animal, IFNULL(S.count,0) as num_sales 
FROM Animals AS A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT animal, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM Sales 
  where idOffice = 1 
  GROUP BY animal
) AS S
ON A.animal = S.animal
ORDER BY A.id ASC;`

and get this results but only for Office A and not between dates:

`| animal   |num_sales|
|----------|---------|
| dog      |    1    |
| cat      |    1    |
| bird     |    0    |
| snake    |    0    |`

I need to get this info for each office and between sales dates in one query.

I hope you can help me.Thanks and best regards.

Comment: All sales are between 2015-06-10 00:00:00 and 2015-06-12 23:59:59, so what's the point of including that criteria in this question? And if you only want office A's sales, why are you including all offices in the result?

Comment: I want a result that show all sales of all animal for each office, the example  is with the Office A but i need for each office.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :)

```
SELECT O.office, A.animal, count(*) num_sales
FROM (Sales S INNER JOIN Animals A on S. animal=A.animal) INNER JOIN Offices O on S.idOffice=O.id
WHERE (S.date BETWEEN '2015-06-10 00:00:00' AND '2015-06-12 23:59:59')
GROUP BY O.id, A.id
```

EDIT:
If you want 0 values, use this one instead:

```
SELECT O.office, A.animal, COALESCE(count(S.id),0) num_sales
FROM (Offices O JOIN Animals A) LEFT JOIN Sales S ON S.idOffice=O.id AND S.animal=A.animal
WHERE (S.date BETWEEN '2015-06-10 00:00:00' AND '2015-06-12 23:59:59') OR ISNULL(S.id)
GROUP BY O.id, A.id
```

Comment: Thank you !!! but i need all of sales for each office and animals incudes 0 values. Can you help me?

Comment: @gzk82 Use natural join in that case

Comment: Thank you !!! but not works how i like becouse is the same results for each office and the result doesn´t show all animals. I think you are closed for the solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

The data set:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS offices;

CREATE TABLE offices
(office_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,office VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO offices VALUES
(1 ,'office A'),
(2 ,'office B'),
(3 ,'office C');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS animals;

CREATE TABLE animals
(animal_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,animal VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO animals VALUES
(101   ,'dog'),
(102   ,'cat'),
(103   ,'bird'),
(104   ,'snake');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales;

CREATE TABLE sales
(sale_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,animal_id INT NOT NULL
,office_id INT NOT NULL
,dt DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO sales VALUES
(1,101,1,'2015-06-10 16:57:23'),
(2,102,1,'2015-06-10 17:47:45'),
(3,101,2,'2015-06-10 18:20:56'),
(4,104,3,'2015-06-11 10:33:47'),
(5,103,2,'2015-06-11 11:41:29'),
(6,104,2,'2015-06-11 12:59:36'),
(7,102,3,'2015-06-11 13:01:41'),
(8,101,2,'2015-06-12 13:56:58'),
(9,102,3,'2015-06-12 14:17:34');
```

The query:

```
SELECT o.office
     , a.animal
     , COUNT(s.sale_id) total 
  FROM offices o 
 CROSS 
  JOIN animals a
  LEFT 
  JOIN sales s 
    ON s.office_id = o.office_id 
   AND s.animal_id = a.animal_id 
   AND s.dt BETWEEN '2015-06-10 00:00:00' AND '2015-06-12 23:59:59' 
 GROUP 
    BY o.office_id
     , a.animal_id;

     +----------+--------+-------+
     | office   | animal | total |
     +----------+--------+-------+
     | office A | dog    |     1 |
     | office A | cat    |     1 |
     | office A | bird   |     0 |
     | office A | snake  |     0 |
     | office B | dog    |     2 |
     | office B | cat    |     0 |
     | office B | bird   |     1 |
     | office B | snake  |     1 |
     | office C | dog    |     0 |
     | office C | cat    |     2 |
     | office C | bird   |     0 |
     | office C | snake  |     1 |
     +----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Good. The convention on SO is to 'Accept' the solution that you feel best addresses your problem.